# Java Weka: How to specify split percentage?

Tags: java, weka

I have written the code to create the model and save it. It works fine. My understanding is data, by default, is split in 10 folds. I want data to be split into two sets (training and testing) when I create the model. On Weka UI, I can do it by using "Percentage split" radio button. I want to know how to do it through code. I want it to be split in two parts 80% being the training and 20% being the testing. Here is my code.

```
        FilteredClassifier model = new FilteredClassifier();
        model.setFilter(new StringToWordVector());
        model.setClassifier(new NaiveBayesMultinomial());
        try {
            model.buildClassifier(trainingSet);
        } catch (Exception e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(
                        "/Users/me/models/MyModel.model"));
        oos.writeObject(model);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
```

trainingSet here is already populated Instances object. Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the UI class [`ClassifierPanel`](https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka/src/main/java/weka/gui/explorer/ClassifierPanel.java)'s method `startClassifier()`, I found the following code:

```java
// Percent split

int trainSize = (int) Math.round(inst.numInstances() * percent
    / 100);
int testSize = inst.numInstances() - trainSize;
Instances train = new Instances(inst, 0, trainSize);
Instances test = new Instances(inst, trainSize, testSize);
```

so after randomizing your dataset...

```java
trainingSet.randomize(new java.util.Random(0));
```

... I suggest you split your `trainingSet`in the same way:

```java
int trainSize = (int) Math.round(trainingSet.numInstances() * 0.8);
int testSize = trainingSet.numInstances() - trainSize;
Instances train = new Instances(trainingSet, 0, trainSize);
Instances test = new Instances(trainingSet, trainSize, testSize);
```

then use `Classifier#buildClassifier(Instances data)` to train the classifier with 80% of your set instances:

```java
model.buildClassifier(train);
```

**UPDATE**: thanks to @ChengkunWu's answer, I added the randomizing step above.

Comment: The answer is right. But in that case, the splitting into train and test set is not random. How can I split the dataset into train and test test randomly ? I mean... Randomly take data from dataset and form the train and test set.

Answer (score 8):

You might also want to randomize the split as well.

```
data.randomize(new java.util.Random(0));
```

Comment: @Jan Eglinger This short but VERY important note should be added to the accepted answer

Comment: why do we need to randomize the split?! could you specify this in your answer. Thank you

Comment: @F505 I randomize my entire dataset before splitting so i can have more confidence that a better distribution of classes will end up in the split sets. this is important (for instance) if the input dataset is sorted on label, though its less effective with wildly skewed data.